# how to write junit test cases for void function which prints output to console

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, automated-tests

I've two functions addKeywords and search which have void return type and search function prints results to the console.
Here is the code

```
 void addKeywords(String video)throws IOException{


    InputStreamReader ip = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ip);

    Integer previousVal=0;

    if(!videoKeyword.containsKey(video) && videoNames.contains(video)){
        videoKeyword.put(video,new HashSet<String>());
    }
    else if(!videoNames.contains(video)){
        System.out.println("Video is not a part of lookup");
    }

    System.out.println("Enter keywords for video");
    String keyword =br.readLine();

    if(!keywordLength.containsKey(video))
        keywordLength.put(video, 0);

    if((keywordLength.get(video)+keyword.length())<500){
        videoKeyword.get(video).add(keyword);
        previousVal=keywordLength.get(video);
        keywordLength.put(video, previousVal+keyword.length());
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Maximum length exceeded for video "+ video);
    }
    if(!kewordVideo.containsKey(keyword)){
        kewordVideo.put(keyword,new HashSet<String>());
    }
    kewordVideo.get(keyword).add(video);
 }

 void search(String searchKey){
    for (Entry<String, HashSet<String>> entry : videoKeyword.entrySet()) {
        for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
            if (s.startsWith(searchKey)) {
                System.out.println(searchKey+" is mapped to "+entry.getKey());
                break;
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

I have written junit tests

```
 public class MyUnitTest extends CultureMachineAssignment {
      CultureMachineAssignment testObj =new CultureMachineAssignment();
      testObj.insertDataIntoSet();
      testObj.addkeywords("video1");

     @Test
     public void testVideo() {
        assertEquals("video1", testObj.search("abcd"));
    }
}
```

I am getting following errors

The method assertEquals(Object, Object) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments 
     (String, void)

- Syntax error on token ""video1"", delete 
   this token
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
   construct(s)

I am not sure if this is the correct way to write junit test cases for functions with void return type and which prints output to console.
Can someone please tell me correct code ?

Comment: Why don't you simply let the `search(...)` method return a String ?

Comment: Issue with allowing search method return is there may be multiple outputs so once i return remaining will not be printed so I am not using return

Comment: You can also return a `List<String>` or a `String[]` and then write a function to print it.

Comment: fine i did it but still I am having syntax errors which i am not able to resolve

Comment: What is your syntax errors ?

Comment: Syntax error on token "insertDataIntoSet", Identifier expected after this token in MyUnitTest  for ` testObj.insertDataIntoSet();
      testObj.addkeywords("video1");`

Comment: It seems you are calling methods of the `testObj`directly in the class and not in a method. Only fields can be here. Encapsulate your initialisation with a `init()` method along with the annotation `@Before`.

Comment: I did that with `@Before
 public void init() throws IOException{
  testObj1.insertDataIntoSet();
     testObj1.addKeywords("video1");
        
 }` now after running I am getting java.lang.stackoverflow error

Comment: It depends of what you want... 
`@Before`execute the method each time before a test method.
`@BeforeClass`excutes the method one time a the initilialization. Or you can just cut/paste your two lines of code in your `testVideo` method.
In a general way, you have to handle your lists (clear it if needed)

Comment: I tried all 3 options still I am getting java.lang.Stack()Overflow error .`java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at cultureMachine.CultureMachineAssignment.<init>(CultureMachineAssignment.java:13)
 at cultureMachine.CultureMachineTestCases.<init>(CultureMachineTestCases.java:11)
 at cultureMachine.CultureMachineTestCases.<init>(CultureMachineTestCases.java:14)
`

Comment: `extends CultureMachineAssignment` don't have to be here, I think. It is complicated to help you more, we don't have all the code for testing.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the System.out or System.err messages with `System.setOut(printStream) and System.setErr(printStream)` functions.

That way you will be able to get the System.out messages into a printstream object and can read it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `System.out` to the constructor of the class in the form of `PrintStream` and then write to it later. So you can replace it in a unit test with a custom stream into a `String` and verify it:

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(byteArrayOutputStream);

ps.println("...");

assertEquals("expectedOutput", byteArrayOutputStream.toString())
```

(You should also pass `System.in` as a parameter to further decouple)

---

### Update

As @kryger pointed out: You should return the result as a `String` and move printing responsibility to the caller.

Comment: If we were to recommend a code change to help OP fix the testing problem, I'd argue that passing a mutable, writable  `Stream` is a much worse solution than making the method more functional by making it return the results and move printing responsibility to the caller (as per *romfet*'s comment)

Comment: @kryger Yes, I agree.

Comment: "romfret" with an "r" ;). We are all agree so.

Comment: Obviously, "@romfret with an **r**" (or even *two* "r"s :)). Sadly autocomplete doesn't work for people who didn't comment under the same question.

Comment: @kryger Oh yes I see... no prob anyway ! :)